Show frequency in a violin plot
I'm using matplotlib's violinplot and I'd like to see the frequency values in the X axis.
This is my MWE:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(size=100)
plt.violinplot(data)
plt.show()

which generates the following plot:

I'd like the X axis to show the frequency (count of values). Is that possible?

Violin plots are using KDEs. The "X" value is a density (the total area of one half sums to 1). Thus, it doesn't really make sense to show "counts".
It looks like you rather want a hist, in which you can define the exact bins:
plt.hist(data)

Output:


But that doesn't indicate how many observations have a given Y value. For instance, in my 100 data points, the associated histogram shows there are about 14 observations with a value close to 0, only 5 close to -2, etc. Those are the values I'd like in the X axis.

@DidacBusquets I see, I misunderstood your question then. Violinplots show normalized KDE, thus there are not counts (it wouldn't really make sense since there are no defined bins).

I've edited the answer to suggest an alternative.

Indeed, I could use a simple histogram, but violinplots are nicer, and they work well when showing several ones next to each other. And still, I think it would be useful to have the option of showing the frequency. Even if it's a density plot, it makes sense.

@Didac I actually doesn't make sense. Let's imagine for the sake of the argument that we're using np.random.seed(0) ; data = np.random.normal(size=100) as example. All numbers (floats) are unique. Which means that for a small enough bin the counts are all 1. Conversely, for a large enough bin, the count is 100. In between you have an infinite number of possibilities. KDEs are continuous, not discrete. To be able to show counts, you must be able to define a bin: "There are 13 values between -1.10616648 and -0.62389204". You cannot do this with a continuous representation.

But even in a KDE (a normal KDE plot, not the violin) there are values in the Y axis. I know they are unit less, but they may provide more context to the reader.
